How to do session-based authentication when combining FastAPI with Django?
For the backend of a project, we are combining FastAPI and Django.

Why FastAPI?

We need to use WebSockets and FastAPI supports that natively
We like the Pydantic validation & auto-documentation it include


Why Django?

We want to make use of the builtin authentication & authorization (permissions) features
We like to be able to use its ORM


Why not Django-ninja?

It does not support WebSockets


Why not Django with Django Rest Framework for the API & with Channels for WebSockets?

We prefer FastAPIs API features over DRF
We like that FastAPI supports WebSockets natively



We would like to authenticate & authorize the FastAPI endpoints based on the auth features that Django has (builtin User sessions & permissions). I'm struggling to find a good way of securing the FastAPI endpoints with the sessions from Django.
In the code below you can see the current setup:

main.py: FastAPI is set up here with (1) a router containing the FastAPI endpoints and (2) the Django application mounted
router.py: Contains the FastAPI endpoints, I would like to make use of Django's builtin user sessions for authentication & authorization of the FastAPI endpoints.

## main.py (FastAPI)

import os

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from django.apps import apps

from fastapi import FastAPI

from service_using_websockets.endpoints import router

# Setup FastAPI w/ and include the api router
api = FastAPI()
api.include_router(router, prefix="/api")

# Mount the Django backend application to the api
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "backend.settings")
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
api.mount("/backend", get_asgi_application())


## router.py (FastAPI, using Django auth)

from fastapi import APIRouter, Response
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

router = APIRouter()

@router.post("/login")
def login(credentials: HTTPBasicCredentials = Depends(security)):
    user = authenticate(username=credentials.username, password=credentials.password)
    
    # User authenticated w/ Django, now create a session
    if user is not None:
        # TODO: this works, but might be bad security-wise as we
        # are working around Django's security middleware this way
        session = Session()
        session.session_key = Session.objects.generate_session_key()
        session.session_data = {}  # You can store additional session data here
        session.expire_date = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)  # Set session expiry
        session.save()

        # Set the session ID in the cookie
        response.set_cookie(key="sessionid", value=session.session_key, httponly=True)
        return {"message": "User logged in successfully"}
    else:
        return {"message": "Invalid username or password"}

@router.get("/protected-endpoint")
def example_protected_endpoint(request: Request):
    session_id = request.cookies.get("session_id")
    if session_id is None or int(session_id) not in sessions_in_db:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=401,
            detail="Login and get a valid session",
        )
    # Get the user from the session
    user = get_user_from_session(int(session_id))
    # ... do some endpoint logic for this user

My current approach might work, but I think security-wise it might not be the best approach to directly create sessions like this. I believe we're skipping a whole bunch of Django's security middleware by doing it like this. Is there a better way to re-use Django's user sessions & permissions to securing FastAPI endpoints?

I would suggest having a look at this and this

Related answers that might prove helpful could be found here and here

Don’t break the framework.

Does it have to be sessions? If token-based authentication would work, you can just use Django as an auth backend to issue tokens and then let FastAPI validate the token. That way you wouldn't have to entangle FastAPI and Django.

@Vegard We would like the user to be able to login once with their username/password used on signup and then being allowed to access the FastAPI endpoints (indirectly via interaction with the frontend UI) as long as their session is valid. Would that still work with your proposed approach? If so, would you mind proposing an answer with some code examples? I'm struggling to picture how your approach works in practice.

Depending on any specifics as to what you mean by "as long as their session is valid", it should indeed work. I'll see about making some examples.

As discussed in a comment, this answer does not use session-based authentication, it instead uses token-based authentication.
(A) Set up a Django instance with DRF + simplejwt

Install simplejwt with crypto dependency (for secure verification in your FastAPI instance):

pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt[crypto]


Configure Django to use simplejwt

# settings.py
from datetime import timedelta

SECRET_KEY = "" # Add key here, whether you read it from .env or w/e

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # [...]
    'rest_framework',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    # Lifecycle for access token
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=60),

    # Lifecycle for refresh token - if this expires, user has to log in again
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=7),

    'ALGORITHM'   : 'HS512',
    'SIGNING_KEY' : SECRET_KEY
}


Add auth endpoints

# urls.py
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenRefreshView,
)

# if simplejwt's default flow is good enough:
urlpatterns = [
    path('token/obtain/',  TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain'),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]

If you need a custom login flow, here's a basic start:
# auth_views.py
from django.contrib.auth                      import authenticate

from rest_framework.views                     import APIView
from rest_framework.permissions               import AllowAny
from rest_framework.response                  import Response


class LoginView(APIView):
    '''
    Authenticates the user, and if successful, returns the user object as well as tokens for access & refresh
    '''
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    serializer_class   = LoginResponseSerializer
    http_method_names  = ['post']

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        email    = request.data.get('email')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        user     = authenticate(username=email, password=password)

        if user:
            refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
            serializer = UserLoginSerializer(user)
            return Response({
                'refresh': str(refresh),
                'access': str(refresh.access_token),
                'user_details': serializer.data
            }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({'error': 'Invalid credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

(B) How to consume this auth
From your frontend, CLI, whichever, make a request equivalent to simplejwt docs, just make sure to pick the correct endpoint from your urls.py.
"First-time" login:
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"username": "davidattenborough", "password": "boatymcboatface"}' \
  http://localhost:8000/api/token/obtain/

Fetching a new access token based on a valid refresh token:
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"refresh":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX3BrIjoxLCJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImNvbGRfc3R1ZmYiOiLimIMiLCJleHAiOjIzNDU2NywianRpIjoiZGUxMmY0ZTY3MDY4NDI3ODg5ZjE1YWMyNzcwZGEwNTEifQ.aEoAYkSJjoWH1boshQAaTkf8G3yn0kapko6HFRt7Rh4"}' \
  http://localhost:8000/api/token/refresh/

If you need to simplify it for the frontend consumer, you could "wrap" this in a FastAPI endpoint, such that your FastAPI /login/ let's say will under the hood pass the token(s) or username+password to Django whenever necessary.
You can do the same for your other endpoints - if the token doesn't verify, you fetch a new access token based on the refresh token and see if that will verify.
That means the frontend doesn't have to keep track of two different servers, nor the token lifetime cycle. So it'll appear to the frontend as if session auth is in place except that it's arbitrarily time-limited - but so long as the clients make a request within the lifetime of the refresh token, they "session" will keep on being renewed.
But it's also added complexity for your FastAPI endpoint(s), so that's a call you'll have to work out.
(C) Verify tokens inside of FastAPI, using PyJWT
# jwt.py
import jwt

# Has to be the same key that you used as SIGNING_KEY for simplejwt in Django
SECRET_KEY = ""

# Has to include the same algorithm that you used for simplejwt config in Django
ALGORITHM  = ["HS256"]

def verify(access_token):
    try:
        decoded_token = jwt.decode(access_token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=ALGORITHM)
        return decoded_token
    except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
        # Token has expired - call Django's refresh-endpoint to get a new token set and repeat verification?
    except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
        # Token was invalid for other reasons - maybe the token never was valid. Redirect to login? Up to you.

# fastapi.py or wherever
from .jwt import verify

# on incoming request:
token = request.headers.get('Authorization')
if verify(token):
    pass
else:
    raise Exception("Auth was not valid")

